# XGBoost (Python) Doesn't seem to be scaling well on AWS instance

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xgboost

So I wrote some code that uses sklearn's grid search to train a number of xgboost models. I compared performance on my laptop (MBP w/8-core I9) and an AWS c5n.18xlarge instance, 72 vcores 190-something gb ram. It's barely using any ram but my dataset is tiny (a few mb, less than 20k rows). Not sure what's going on, is pickling taking forever on AWS? Is there a bottleneck in storage? FYI this is on Anaconda. Tried messing with the number of threads/workers in xgb/gridsearchcv params and it seems to perform best with -1 for xgboost and 1 worker for gridsearchcv.

Doing 5 fold CV, did a test run with search params:

search_params = {'n_estimators': [300, 500],
'max_depth': [3, 4, 5]}

Took about 8 min 15s on the instance and 10m 42s on my laptop. Code is pasted below. Running top on the instance shows me that the cpu is running at or close to 7200% until the program finishes.

I included as much code as possible w/minimal obfuscation. What this does is it holds out categories of attributes for different models that it builds, but this shouldn't effect training speed performance, or at least not scaling...

Note that cats is a dict. of sets of attributes, so for example if all of my attributes with different vehicles i.e. [airplane, car, helicopter, bus, boat, jetski], cats would be along the lines of {'air': [airplane, helicopter], water: [boat, jetski], land: [car, bus]}

```
grid_models = {'datasets': datasets,
               'dataset_name': csv_f_name}

search_params = {'n_estimators': [300, 500],
                 'max_depth': [3, 4, 5]}

for cat in cats.keys():
    print('Training on all attributes except for', cat)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, dataset_name = datasets[0]
    X_train, X_test = X_train.drop(cats[cat], axis=1), X_test.drop(cats[cat], axis=1)
    scale_pos_weight = len(y_1_train[y_1_train == 0]) / len(y_1_train[y_1_train == 1])
    fbeta_scorer = metrics.make_scorer(metrics.fbeta_score, beta=b)
    
    xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='logloss',
                            objective='binary:logistic', booster='gbtree', verbosity = 0,
                            n_jobs=-1, random_state=1, scale_pos_weight=scale_pos_weight)
    
    search = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, search_params, verbose=2,
                            scoring=fbeta_scorer, n_jobs=1)

    model = search.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    fbeta = metrics.fbeta_score(y_test, y_pred, beta=b)
    f1 = metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
    roc_auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)

    results_dict = {
        'est': model,
        'accuracy': accuracy,
        'fbeta': fbeta,
        'f1': f1,
        'roc_auc': roc_auc,
        'scorer': fbeta_scorer}
    
    grid_models['without_'+cat] = results_dict
    
date = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M')
models_f_name = date+'_model.bin'
with open(models_f_name, 'wb') as f:
    pkl.dump(grid_models, f)
```